# Copy IntelliJ "Inspections" settings to default

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

I've changed a bunch of the settings in the "Inspections" section of the IntelliJ preferences.  I realized that I mistakenly changed them in the "Project Defaults" profile, rather than the "Defaults" profile, and I don't see any way to copy them over.

I tried the "Copy" button, but that creates a new profile.  I tried exporting and then importing, but that also creates a new profile.

Is there any way to do this?  Perhaps the settings are hidden away in some file I can edit?

For what it's worth, I'm using the OSX Community version, though I imagine the answer will be similar among the different versions.